# With angular animations, can I wait for them to finish before starting another one using only one variable?

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

To better explain what I mean, say I have two divs as below:

```
<div class="animate-if" ng-if="something">
<div class="animate-if" ng-if="!something>
```

And an animation that looks like this:

```
.animate-if.ng-enter, .animate-if.ng-leave {
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}
.animate-if.ng-enter,
.animate-if.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.animate-if.ng-leave,
.animate-if.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Can I, somehow, tell the elements not to appear until the animation is finished, WITHOUT the use of another variable? I know that via a timeout that lasts the duration of the animation and two variables for each div, I can do this, but is there a cleaner way? As it stands using this method, both divs will (briefly) be visible, and it moves things around on view a lot.